# Why does Laravel Task Scheduler cron use >> instead of > to redirect to dev/null?

Tags: linux, laravel, stdout

The Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling) say to add this to your cron for the scheduler

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I'm just curious why they are using >> (which I understand to mean append) instead of > (which I understand to mean write) when it's going to dev/null anyway?

Answer (score 0):

**It makes no difference** whether you `append`(>>) or write(>) to /dev/null in this perticular case.

But **it may be useful in some cases**:

for example:

```
OUTF=/tmp/my.log
if [ "$QUIET" = y ];
    OUTF=/dev/null
fi

# We need to keep track of multiple runs, so...
my_program >> $OUTF
```

In the above examlpe when I don't want to log anything I can set `$OUTF` to `/dev/null` but if I do want to log then the `my_program >> $OUTF` line makes sure that the output is appened no matter what.

But you need not be concerned about this in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I still wonder if there is a specific reason why it's used in the that way specifically in the Laravel docs.

Comment: But it doesn't specifically answer why in this specific situation for Laravel it is used that way which is what I'm curious about.